# What is the correct syntax for Swagger 2.0 AWS requestParameters for MessageAttributes ? to map them from body to header

Tags: spring, swagger, amazon-sqs, swagger-2.0

I'm not familiar enough with AWS to verify whether the syntax for mapping requestParameters is correct for AWS Swagger 2.0 config.
The message will be send to SQS with a body like this

```
{
    "QueueUrl": "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/177715257436/MyQueue/",
    "MessageBody": "This is a test message",
    "MessageAttributes": {
        "EndpointURL": {
            "DataType": "String",
            "Value": "my_attribute_value_1"
        }
    }
}
```

I have the next config for Swagger 2.0.
The main thing here is requestParameters, where
**MessageAttributes.EndpointURL.Value is remmapped to -> "method.request.header.EndpointURL"**. I expect to receive this value in **EndpointURL Header** for my method. Also, I set a default value for this Header(EndpointURL) with endpoint path value.

```
 /test:
    post:
      consumes:
        - "application/json"
      parameters:
        - name: EndpointURL
          in: header
          type: string
          default: '/test'
      produces:
        - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "200 response"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/TestDto"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        credentials: "{{RoleARN}}"
        uri: "uri"
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
        requestParameters:
          integration.request.body.MessageBody: "method.request.body.MessageBody"
          integration.request.body.MessageAttributes.EndpointAddress.Value: "method.request.header.EndpointURL"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        type: "aws"
```

Next question

1 Can anyone verify/check whether this is correct syntax for remapping values from
integration.request.body.MessageAttributes to method.request.header.EndpointURL. ?

2 If it's correct I expect to receive this Header value in a method for SQS Listener.

```
@SqsListener(value = "${messaging.service-queue-url}")
public void onMessage(String message, @Header("EndpointURL") String endpointUrl) {
}
```

I used next docs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html#SQS-SendMessage-request-MessageAttributes

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-aws-services.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html

https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/index.html#listener-method-arguments

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-metadata.html#sqs-message-attributes

Thank you.